# What happens when my kid buys something with Apple Family?

Tags: macos, ios, family-sharing

I set up an Apple Family and my kid wants to buy something. The thing is though he knows his Apple ID password.

What happens when my kid buys something? Does it charge from my credit card?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Purchase Sharing enabled for your Apple Family, then it depends on whether Ask to Buy is enabled:

When [Ask to Buy](https://support.apple.com/en-us/105055) is enabled, then any download of a new app must be approved by a Family organizer.

Ask to Buy is only enable for people under 18 in your family, and is enabled by default for children under 13.

Ask to Buy applies to all downloads including free apps or if the child has a balance.

---

If you do not have Ask to Buy but Purchase Sharing is enabled then the child can download anything and it will charge to their balance first, then your payment method.

If you have Purchase Sharing disabled, then it will charge their balance and payment method.